# Saving a cookie with RestSharp

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rest, restsharp

I am trying to get a cookie to persist between RestClients and app sessions for WinPhone 7 Mango using RestSharp.

If I use a single RestClient instance the cookie persists. I want the cookie to last between RestClient instances and when a user returns to the app.

Comment: I've never used RestSharp but with regular HttpClient you can add items to the CookieCollection. Serializing cookies is more of a pain though -- I ended up getting all the relevant cookie properties off of each cookie (cookie crumbs? :)), and storing them in my own datastructure that I then created new cookies with.

Comment: There is only a few properties in the cookie that I need so serialising just what I need would not be to bad. I was hoping there may a native solution which is not looking very likely :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RestSharp have recently added automatic cookie support!

> RestSharp 102.4+ supports using a shared System.Net.CookieContainer for all requests from the same IRestClient. By doing so, any cookies set or unset in responses will be used in subsequent requests. In order to use a shared CookieContainer, simply set the property on your RestClient instance before using it:

```
var client = new RestClient ("http://server/");
client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

[Documentation: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Cookies](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Cookies)

Answer (score 0):

**Cookie value must be encoded.**

```
if ( header["Set-Cookie"] != null )
{
string value = header["Set-Cookie"];

Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9");//may be utf-8

value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value, iso);
Cookie moCookie = new Cookie( "Cookie", value);
moCookie.Domain = GatewayURI.Trim();
CookieContainer CommCookie = new CookieContainer();
CommCookie.Add( moCookie );
request.CookieContainer = CommCookie;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to manually save the cookie info there is no native support in RestSharp for saving your cookie between sessions.

Comment: RestSharp allows cookie reusing. See @Eldar answer.